# how to make @FindAll annotation stop looking for object once the right one is found?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

OS: Windows 10

Selenium Version: 3.4

**@FINDALL** annotation is supposed to match at least one of the given criteria.

**Here is the OR :** 
URL for WebPage : http://store.demoqa.com/

WebElement : -

```
@FINDALL ({

@findby(xpath = "//input[@name='s']"),

@findby(xpath = "//a[contains(.,'Magic Mouse')]")

})
public WebElement Header__txtSearch;
```

I am trying to verify element on page with multiple locators.

When I give 2 correct values of XPath, then the driver identifies it quickly on the webpage and returns normally. But when I give the first one as Correct and second one as Incorrect , then it still returns true that element is found but it waits for the object timeout that was provided while initializing the driver(implicit wait).

Isn't there a way where if it finds the first element then it immediately returns us as true instead of going to match the next locator, So that no more time is taken for the test execution to move forward.

**How can it be stopped after finding the correct locater info ??**

Or is there a **workaround** for this in which I can use multiple locators for one element so that driver return true as soon as it matches the one locator correctly?

Comment: Do you need to get WebElement as output or boolean?

Comment: @Andersson I need WebDriver to return the flow back to my program as soon as it matches any one locator from the provided.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to combine selectors into one by "|"? like:

```
@findby(xpath = "//input[@name='s']|//a[contains(.,'Magic Mouse')]")
public WebElement Header__txtSearch;
```

Comment: Yes I have already know this but this xpath was just an example. I want to use multiple locators. suppose ID and XPath for the same element that is why I am trying to use @FindAll annotation. But the problem faced is that the driver doesnt return until it searches for all locators. It should return back to the program as soon as it finds one locator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `or` in the to get the first matching locator.

```
@findby(xpath = "//input[@name='s'] or //a[contains(.,'Magic Mouse')]")
public WebElement Header__txtSearch;
```

Comment: Yes I have already know this but this xpath was just an example. I want to use multiple locators. suppose ID and XPath for the same element that is why I am trying to use @FindAll annotation. But the problem faced is that the driver doesnt return until it searches for all locators. It should return back to the program as soon as it finds one locator.

Comment: @samnit `@FINDALL` will look for all the locators. The `or` condition will give you exactly what you want, it will return as soon as it found on locator.

Comment: So, is there a wok around where I can use multiple locators like ID,CSS,Xpath for single element and it gets returned as soon as it finds any one of them.

Comment: @samnit You can create a single XPath (or preferably a CSS selector) that contains all the various ways to locate an element that you want to use.